# Limit fadeOut() to 3 steps per second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery's `.fadeOut()` function to fade out an element over a period of 3 seconds, and it's fading too smoothly to meet WCAG 2.0 standards of 3 steps per second.

Is there a way to limit the animation steps to 3 steps per second? It'll be choppy, but accessible.

My current code is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<p>This is some text</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut(3000)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "3 steps per second" means?

Comment: Why not use CSS, you have fine grain control using keyframe.  [Using Multi-Step Animations and Transitions](https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/).

Comment: j08691: Instead of smooth animation transition that changes several times per second, WCAG dictates that an animation can only change 3 times per second. So basically the animation would change from a perfectly smooth transition to choppy, as the <p> is only doing 3 fade steps per second.

[Second 0]--Opacity: 0,Opacity: 10,Opacity: 20 [Second 1]--Opacity: 30,Opacity: 40,Opacity: 50 [Second 2]...

Comment: erik: The project specs are dictating that I use jquery to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the rate (in milliseconds) at which the animation fires, using `jQuery.fx.interval`.

```js
// Change the interval to 333ms you have 3 intervals per second
jQuery.fx.interval = 333;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut(3000)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<p>This is some text</p>
```

You can read more about changing the animation interval [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.interval/).

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for, except the interval would be 333 (so it's changing 3 times per second)

Comment: @EmilySamanthaHeiner great! I've udated my answer. Tick it if it helped :-)